# From a Web App, Can I Query a Dynamics Entity Field Option Set?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been assigned the opportunity to build a web app that interfaces with Microsoft Dynamics. One of the goals/requirements is to have all the drop downs (select) in the UI display the value and text of specific Option Set fields from one of my Dynamics Entities. Is that possible?

Using FetchXML Builder (XRMToolBox) I can build a query against an entity and get its records. However, I do not know if it is possible to pull a field's Option Set meta-data from an Entity. **Is it possible to pull the value (ID) and text of an Option Set?**

Comment: @ArunVinoth, thank you so much for your response! This may very well answer my question. My testing shall prove it out and I'll share the outcome. Thank you for your patience and kind response.

Comment: if that answer helped you, pls upvote it.

Comment: While this certainly opens the door, it has not solved my problem. I'm using version 8.1 not 9. It appears that the example in the article referenced above is not fully supported in 8.1. I'm receiving a "Bad Request - error in query syntax" using the following.

https://mycrminstance.com/MyDev/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='myEntity')/Attributes(LogicalName='some_attribute')/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=GlobalOptionSet($select=Options)

Comment: Create a new question with your sample code to assist. It should work in any version, something wrong with payload so that 400 Bad request is throwing.

Comment: Because I'm using 8.1, the syntax requires that I have and use the GUID of the Entity and the GUID of the Attribute I need metadata for. Making these changes fixes the issue.